# Perl replace with variable

Tags: scripting, perl, regex

I'm trying to replace a word in a string. The word is stored in a variable so naturally I do  this:

```
$sentence = "hi this is me";
$foo=~ m/is (.*)/;

$foo = $1;
$sentence =~ s/$foo/you/;
print $newsentence;
```

But this doesn't work.

Any idea on how to solve this? Why this happens?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have pointed out you were using the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl lets you interpolate a string into a regular expression, as many of the answers have already shown. After that string interpolation, the result has to be a valid regex.

In your original try, you used the match operator, `m//`, that immediately tries to perform a match. You could have used the regular expression quoting operator in it's place:

```
$foo = qr/me/;
```

You can either bind to that directory or interpolate it:

```
$string =~ $foo;
$string =~ s/$foo/replacement/;
```

You can read more about `qr//` in [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Answer (score 4):

You have to replace the same variable, otherwise `$newsentence` is not set and Perl doesn't know what to replace:

```
$sentence = "hi this is me";
$foo = "me";
$sentence =~ s/$foo/you/;
print $sentence;
```

If you want to keep `$sentence` with its previous value, you can copy `$sentence` into `$newsentence` and perform the substitution, that will be saved into `$newsentence`:

```
$sentence = "hi this is me";
$foo = "me";
$newsentence = $sentence;
$newsentence =~ s/$foo/you/;
print $newsentence;
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to copy `$sentence` to `$newsentence`.

```
$sentence = "hi this is me";

$foo = "me";

$newsentence = $sentence;
$newsentence =~ s/$foo/you/;

print $newsentence;
```

Comment: The idiomatic perl for this would likely be `$old = "me you"; $chg = "me"; ($new = $old) =~ s/$chg/you/; print $new;` -- note the `($new = $old) =~ s///;` which does the copy and change as one conceptual grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Even for small scripts, please 'use strict' and 'use warnings'.  Your code snippet uses $foo and $newsentence without initialising them, and 'strict' would have caught this.  Remember that '=~' is for matching and substitution, not assignment.  Also be aware that regexes in Perl aren't word-bounded by default, so the example expression you've got will set $1 to 'is me', the 'is' having matched the tail of 'this'.

Assuming you're trying to turn the string from 'hi this is me' to 'hi this is you', you'll need something like this:

```
my $sentence = "hi this is me";
$sentence =~ s/\bme$/\byou$/;
print $sentence, "\n";
```

In the regex, '\b' is a word boundary, and '$' is end-of-line.  Just doing 's/me/you/' will also work in your example, but would probably have unintended effects if you had a string like 'this is merry old me', which would become 'this is yourry old me'.